# Installing matplotlib using pip gives errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pip

I want to import matplotlib to my python code but unfortunately it gives errors when installing. I could successfully install numpy but when installing matplotlib it gives Exception error. I am using Python 3.7.0 version.

```
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

I used above command.Following error appeared in cmd.

```
C:\Users\ASUS>python -m pip install matplotlib
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 333, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 313, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self._populate_link(req)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 279, in _populate_link
    req.link = self.finder.find_requirement(req, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 901, in find_requirement
    req.name, specifier=req.specifier, hashes=hashes,
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 883, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 828, in find_all_candidates
    project_url, link_evaluator=link_evaluator,
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 796, in process_project_url
    page_links = list(parse_links(html_page))
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 346, in wrapper_wrapper
    return list(fn(page))
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 360, in parse_links
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 46, in parse
    p = HTMLParser(tb, namespaceHTMLElements=namespaceHTMLElements)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 123, in __init__
    getPhases(debug).items()])
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_utils.py", line 121, in wrapped
    cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 446, in getPhases
    class Phase(with_metaclass(getMetaclass(debug, log))):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 851, in __new__
    resolved_bases = types.resolve_bases(bases)
AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'resolve_bases'
```

I tried several times with several commands relative to the above and restarted and tried again. But unable to install. Since I am new to this can anyone help me to solve this. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: if the python path is configured properly, simply 'pip install matplotlib' should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: 'pip install matplotlib' I tried this command also but the same error msg appeared.Since other python programs are running properly I think python is correctly configured.

Comment: One more thing to try ... try pip freeze and check the list if you can see matplotlib installed. If it is installed, try 'pip uninstall matplotlib' and then install it again 'pip install matplotlib'. Also double check your PYTHONPATH and PATH variables. Honestly, it is very difficult to debug it this way. I can only just suggest options. :).

Comment: Open `C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\types.py` and verify there a function `resolve_bases` in it. Also check you don't have any other `types.py` lying around.

Answer (score -1):

First check whether 'python' code respond correctly. Use 'C:\' path, you can change the path with 'cd ..' code then try the code 'pip install matplotlib'.